# Why my TPath SVG is cut in Fit mode using Stroke

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With Delphi 11 I have a problem with TPath and SVG data.

For exemple, if I put a TPath and set Data with a circle :

```
M13 25C19.6274 25 25 19.6274 25 13C25 6.37258 19.6274 1 13 1C6.37258 1 1 6.37258 1 13C1 19.6274 6.37258 25 13 25Z
```

I set `Width` and `Height` 150x150 and `Stroke.Thickness` to 5.

In Stretch WrapMode it's ok, but if I use Fit, the part at right is out of the TPath.

It's look like, using

- `Strech`, the `Stroke` thickness is inner
- `Fit` mode the thickness is outer

It's really annoying, any solution ?

Comment: Because the code is wrong. I can see in TPathData.FitToRect that it's translating by FitBounds (half the stroke thickness) and then in TCustomPath.UpdateCurrent it gets translated by half the stroke thickness again. I would report it as an issue. Wrap mode of Tile also seems to have a similar issue.

Comment: I have reported the issue here
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-39520

Comment: Thanks, I will try to fix the FMX unit

Comment: How do you fix an FMX unit? The code is there only to help you understand how to use it. The actual code is already compiled. You could create a Helper or a descendant class but the functions in question are protected and so cannot be overridden.

Comment: I copy FMX.Objects to my project, and I fix it.Then when I compile it use this unit instead of the one in sources

Comment: Interesting. How do you choose which one to use at compile time? Do you give it a different name and then cite that in uses?

Comment: When I copy a Delphi unit (`FMX.Objects` or other) to my project directory, I add it to my project and fix it. When I compile, Delphi will check if it's exists in my project, if yes it will take it, otherwise he will use libraries path and then his own source.